# Can Postman access posted values in a test

Tags: postman

I have postman set up to post data to an endpoint.  Ex:

```
{
  "gender": "f",
  "firstName": "bob",
  "lastName": "smith"
}
```

I have a test that extracts information from the response and stores it in environment variables.

Is there a way to access the values that were posted as part of the test.  Something like:

```
pm.request.parameters("gender")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to that specific property:

```
JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).gender
```

And the test could be:

```
pm.test("Check request data", () => {
    pm.expect(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).gender).to.eql('f')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [postman sandbox documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/), you can do the following:

```
var reqBody = JSON.parse(pm.request.body);
... // Access reqBody;
```